# Consolidating images - sprites vs Base64

Tags: javascript, html

On Google some time ago I read an article on optimizing image use.  Basically there is a way to combine multiple images...say small icons into one larger image and then use a method to display the part you need for ecah part of the page.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this.  Cant' seem to find it on google at the moment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is called *CSS Sprites*, knowing that will make it easy to find information about it.

You can read about it for example here:
[CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)
[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/)

Comment: another option for the textually inclined is consolidating to Base64 and parsing then appending to src attributes. ( loss of 33% to do it this way ).

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: Yes, that is an option, but you should also consider that putting images as base64 in the url means that they won't be cached separately, they are only cached if the page document is cached.

Comment: well...caching is such a fuzzy area...you note they are different mechanisms but not how they are different.  If I hit reload what is cached?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: Resources are cached. If you load an image as usual, that is a resource so it's cached by itsself. If you have an image in the form of a base64 string, it will be part of the HTML document and is not cached by itself. The HTML document is a resource, so it will be cached.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best website for this. http://spriteme.org/

It will analyze your website and advise you on what images can be 'sprited' (is that the correct term?) and will generate the new CSS for you and the image(s) sprite(s)

Comment: do you know why spriteme uses the term "background image" instead of "image" ?

Comment: @Chris Aker: I think the use both terms. In the demo/tutorial they have there, they use both, background images and images for the rounded buttons they have in the page. All of them at the end are "sprited" (heck, I feel bad writing 'sprited', is that the appropriate word?).

Comment: perhaps they assume that most are good at separating presentation from structure...hence putting their images as "background-images" in css wrather than direct links in the html...as well